# Inverse of a product of $n$-tuple in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove $x = (a_1 \cdot ... \cdot a_n)^{- 1} = a_n^{- 1} \cdot ... \cdot a_2^{- 1} \cdot a_1^{- 1}$ (1)

If we have,
$a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdot ... \cdot a_{n - 1} \cdot a_n$
is this the same as
$(a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_{n - 1}) \cdot a_n$ and why?

(If so using $(ab)^{- 1} = b^{- 1}a^{- 1}$ I can easly prove (1).) Thanks.

Comment: Use induction. ${}$

Comment: @Kenta S, please give me something more concrete

Comment: In fact, $a_{1} a_{2} \dots a_{n}$ is defined recursively as $(a_{1} a_{2} \dots a_{n-1}) a_{n}$.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti, thanks. If we look at associative law simply as function composition then this looka trivial, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial when $n=1$. Let $n>1$ and suppose it is true for $n-1$.

Then $(a_1\cdots a_n)^{-1}=((a_1\cdots a_{n-1})a_n)^{-1}=a_n^{-1}(a_1\cdots a_{n-1})^{-1}$. Now, by the inductive hypothesis we have $(a_1\cdots a_{n-1})^{-1}=a_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}$, so we are done.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked if this is true $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_n = (a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_{n - 1}) \cdot a_n.$ So, I see this thing are indeed *equal*.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $(a_1\dots a_n)^{-1}=a_n^{-1}\dots a_1^{-1}$.

We'll show this property using the induction on the number of elements of the product of the elements $a_i, i\in I$.

(i) For $n=1$ we have nothing to prove.

(ii) Let's prove that $\mathcal P(n-1)\implies \mathcal P(n)$:
$(a_1\dots a_n)^{-1}=((a_1\dots a_{n-1})a_n)^{-1}\underset{Hp}{=}a_n^{-1}(a_1\dots a_{n-1})^{-1}=a_n^{-1}a_{n-1}^{-1} \dots a_1^{-1}$.